# Difference between coset and subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

My apologies, this must seem like a trivial question, but this image below appeared on Socratica on youtube and I wanted to clarify my thoughts on cosets and subgroups. From the image below, I can see that the left coset $g_1$h is the composition of all elements in the subgroup h in H with an element $g_1$ from outside the set.

I think of this as the elements in H are being "translated" out of the subgroup H and into a different object (a coset altogether).

My question is since the left coset does not contain the identity element, it is therefore not a subgroup? Am I right in this reasoning?

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TCcSZEL_3CQ&t=295) is the video - the system doesn't appear to let me load images with my reputation. 
See 4 min 55 sec

[image]

Comment: It is not acceptable to expect us to watch a video to understand your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right: In this example, the condition $g_1\not\in H$ guarantees that $g_1H$ doesn't contain the identity.

Consider the coset $gH$ for some arbitary $g\in G$. **If** $gH$ **does** contain the identity -- that is, if $e\in\{gh:h\in H\}$, then by definition we have $e=gh$ for some $h\in H$. This is equivalent to saying $g=h^{-1}$. And since $H$ is a group, it contains its own inverses, so we conclude that $g\in H$.

We also get the contrapositive statement: If $g\not\in H$, then $e\not\in gH$, which is my original claim.

Answer (score 2):

You are right. A coset is not necessarily a subgroup and one of the features is what you said that it may not contain the identity. In general you can easily see in any examples that it may not be closed under the group operation.