# What are the conditions for cosets of a certain group to form a group themselves?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, quotient-group

I'm currently watching Scoratica's YouTube series on Group Theory. On one of the videos, the following argument is made ($N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$):
[Condition for the cosets to act like a group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymqNj.png)

I don't understand why $xy \in (xN)(yN)$ is a necessary condition. We haven't even defined what $(xN)(yN)$ means yet. It could be the set formed by multiplying every element in $xN$ by each element of $yN$, it could be the set formed by the union of the sets $xN$ and $yN$, etc. Is there only one definition of the operation $(xN)(yN)$ that allows the cosets to behave like a group? If so why does it include $xy$?

Comment: All group operations are derived from the operation that defines the original group. So in the quotient (where the cosets get multiplied), we have to use that operation.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2426231/977780

Comment: See this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14282/why-do-we-define-quotient-groups-for-normal-subgroups-only).

Comment: I haven't watched the video, so I can't comment on what its maker means by $(xN)(yN)$. But I can tell you that in Group Theory it is generally defined as in your first suggestion; it is the set of all $rs$, where $r$ is in $xN$ and $s$ is in $yN$.

Comment: Given a group $G$ and a subgroup $H\le G$, a more general way to try getting from the cosets $xH$ and $yH$ another coset of $H$ (closure), *by using the representatives $x,y$ and group's operation, only*, is to set:
$$xHyH=x^my^nH$$
for some positive integers $m,n$. But for $(m,n)\ne(1,1)$, the operation turns out to be not even associative, while for $(m,n)=(1,1)$, but $H$ non-normal, it turns out to be not well-defined.

Answer (score 2):

There are two natural approaches to studying groups (and algebraic objects more generally). The first is to study subgroups, and the second is to study their operation-preserving maps (homomorphisms).

Quotients arise naturally from the study of homomorphisms, in that the cosets are the non-empty preimages of the homomorphism. That is, let $\varphi : G \to H$ be a homomorphism. Now let: $\{ \varphi^{-1}(h) : |\varphi^{-1}(h)| > 0 \}$ be the set of preimages that are non-empty.

Take $x \in \varphi^{-1}(h_{1}), y \in \varphi^{-1}(h_{2})$. So $\varphi(xy) = \varphi(x)\varphi(y) = h_{1}h_{2}$.

Note that if $N = \text{ker}(\varphi)$, then $x \in xN, y \in yN, xy \in xyN = xN \cdot yN$.

There are technical tools that need to be developed to equate these concepts, but this is the high level idea as to why cosets appear naturally and why the operation $xN \cdot yN = xyN$ is the correct operation.